# ng2-currency-mask module import issue issue

Tags: angular, angular12

ng2-currency-mask module is not imported on my project.
If I create a dummy project and use it there it is working perfectly.
But in my real project, it is not even importing.

My app.module is this:-

```ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http'
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr'
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core'
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader'
import { DataTablesModule } from "angular-datatables"
import { NgSelect2Module } from 'ng-select2';
import { NgMultiSelectDropDownModule } from 'ng-multiselect-dropdown';
import { CurrencyMaskModule } from 'ng2-currency-mask';

// AoT requires an exported function for factories
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
 
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    CurrencyMaskModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgSelect2Module,
    ToastrModule.forRoot(),
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      defaultLanguage: 'th',
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    DataTablesModule,
    NgMultiSelectDropDownModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My Implementation in html file

```html
<input class="table-input-control text-right" placeholder="Enter here" min="0" currencyMask [(ngModel)]="itemdetail.target">
```

My package.json dependencies are these. Can anyone tell me a fix for this. I am looking for it for so long.

```
{
  "name": "lthl",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/localize": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^10.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.1",
    "datatables.net": "^1.11.4",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.11.4",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.3.8",
    "ng-select2": "^1.4.1",
    "ng2-currency-mask": "^13.0.3",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^14.2.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "select2": "^4.1.0-rc.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.21",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.14",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.47",
    "@types/select2": "^4.0.55",
    "angular-datatables": "^12.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you include your package.json? What error are you getting?

Comment: No error and the module is not imported and ofcourse not working. Because when I write the [options] in my input tag it does not recognize the property. I am including package.json wait a sec.

Comment: What happens if you run `npm install` in your project?

Comment: It says 10 vulnerabilites 1 moderate, 7 high, 2 critical

Comment: Which html file is that input placed?